# Jupyter simple frontend button javascript fails to validate

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am trying Create simple notebook frontend extensions as described here

http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/extending/frontend_extensions.html

This is what I have

```
~$ cat /home/usr/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/my_fancy_module/static/main.js // file my_extension/main.js

define([
    'base/js/namespace' ], function(
    Jupyter ) {
    function load_ipython_extension() {

        var handler = function () {
            alert('this is an alert from my_extension!');
        };

        var action = {
            icon: 'fa-comment-o', // a font-awesome class used on buttons, etc
            help    : 'Show an alert',
            help_index : 'zz',
            handler : handler
        };
        var prefix = 'my_extension';
        var action_name = 'show-alert-usr';

        var full_action_name = Jupyter.actions.register(action, action_name, prefix); // returns 'my_extension:show-alert'
        Jupyter.toolbar.add_buttons_group([full_action_name]);
    }

    return {
        load_ipython_extension: load_ipython_extension
    }; });
```

When I try to install I get validation errors

```
$ jupyter nbextension enable  /home/usr/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/my_fancy_module/static/main.js
--user Enabling notebook extension /home/usr/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/my_fancy_module/static/main.js...
      - Validating: problems found:
        - require?  X /home/usr/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/my_fancy_module/static/main.js
```

I am very new to Python notebooks.

**Additional information/questions:**

When I pip installed my_fance_module it did not copy over the static directory and the .js files inside. I had to manually copy them to ~/usr/.local/ path afterwards.

This is my directory structure

```
.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/my_fancy_module
-- __init__.py
   |static
    --- main.js
```

Also after installing this main.js and running server and notebook shows only main.js and does not show my notebooks anymore on the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried?

`jupyter nbextension install /home/usr/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/my_fancy_module/static/main.js --sys-prefix`

before;

`jupyter nbextension enable  /home/usr/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/my_fancy_module/static/main.js`

Also what version of Jupyter are you working with? Because the path that you indicated appears to be your systems default Python 2.7 that it ships with. If your developing for Jupyter notebook then I think it would be wise to first install [Anaconda](https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/install/linux.html) then install Jupyter notebook through it `conda install notebook` then migrate your files to you Anaconda dir. So let me know if that doesn't work out for you.